# openlayers3 wfs-t save drawing

Tags: save, openlayers-3, geoserver

I'm workin on an OL3 app, where the user will be able to draw, modify and delete polygons and save the changes to GeoServer via WFS-T.

For starting point I've used the solution from here: [wfs-t example app](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-5/) 
I've changed the code a little bit to use a polygon layer from my GeoServer. The draw, modify and delete polygon functions are working great, if I modify or delete a polygon it's also saved, but the new polygon creation is not saved and I can not figure out why. The original app is working without any problem.

I hope somebody also tried to use this app as a starting point and solved this problem. Could someone give me any idea what is the problem?

Tha most important part of the code:

```
    var dirty = {};
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/topp',
    featureType: 'poly',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
var transactWFS = function(p,f) {
    switch(p) {
    case 'insert':
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
        break;
    case 'update':
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
        break;
    case 'delete':
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
        break;
    }
    s = new XMLSerializer();
    str = s.serializeToString(node);
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: str
        }).done();
}

$('.btn-floating').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('darken-2');},
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('darken-2');}
        );

$('.btnMenu').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.btnMenu').removeClass('orange');
    $(this).addClass('orange');
    map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    select.getFeatures().clear();
    map.removeInteraction(select);
    switch($(this).attr('id')) {

    case 'btnSelect':
        interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#f50057', width: 2})
                })
        });
        map.addInteraction(interaction);
        interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function(e) {
            props = e.element.getProperties();
            if (props.status){$('#popup-status').html(props.status);}else{$('#popup-status').html('n/a');}
            if (props.tiendas){$('#popup-tiendas').html(props.tiendas);}else{$('#popup-tiendas').html('n/a');}
            coord = $('.ol-mouse-position').html().split(',');
            overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
            });
        break;

    case 'btnEdit':
        map.addInteraction(select);
        interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: select.getFeatures()
            });
        map.addInteraction(interaction);

        snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
            source: layerVector.getSource()
            });
        map.addInteraction(snap);

        dirty = {};
        select.getFeatures().on('add', function(e) {
            e.element.on('change', function(e) {
                dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                });
            });
        select.getFeatures().on('remove', function(e) {
            f = e.element;
            if (dirty[f.getId()]){
                delete dirty[f.getId()];
                featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                clone.setId(f.getId());
                transactWFS('update',clone);
                }
            });
        break;

    case 'btnDrawPoly':
        interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            type: 'Polygon',
            source: layerVector.getSource()
        });
        map.addInteraction(interaction);
        interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
            transactWFS('insert',e.feature);
        });
        break;

    case 'btnDelete':
        interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
        map.addInteraction(interaction);
        interaction.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e) {
            transactWFS('delete',e.target.item(0));
            interaction.getFeatures().clear();
            selectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
        });
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    });
```

I'm using a single shape file as data store.

The request to the GeoServer after finishing a polygon:

```
 <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http
    ://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001
    /XMLSchema-instance"><Insert><poly xmlns="http://www.openplans.org/topp"><geometry><Polygon xmlns="http
    ://www.opengis.net/gml"><exterior><LinearRing><posList>2274170.418847337 5923526.286802612 2329612.7433635183
     5979783.939620501 2373640.4716557795 5936979.203780803 2330835.735816081 5891728.483035979 2274170.418847337
     5923526.286802612</posList></LinearRing></exterior></Polygon></geometry></poly></Insert></Transaction
    >
```

The response from GeoServer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:TransactionResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http
://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
 xmlns:tiger="http://www.census.gov" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:xlink="http://www
.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation
="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><wfs:TransactionSummary
><wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted><wfs:totalUpdated>0</wfs:totalUpdated><wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs
:totalDeleted></wfs:TransactionSummary><wfs:TransactionResults/><wfs:InsertResults><wfs:Feature><ogc
:FeatureId fid="new0"/></wfs:Feature></wfs:InsertResults></wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

Comment: To answer this we need to know *at least* the XML sent to the server for the Inserts, what type of datastore you are using and what error is logged in the GeoServer log file.

Comment: I've added more detials to the description.

Answer (score 3):

That code sample looks familiar... I wrote this ages ago and surprised this is still working and how many people have used it since. I am pretty certain that the problem is that the geometry column is not called geometry. I believe this must always be called geometry. I have update the example since to work with Geoserver 2.8 and OpenLayers 3.16.

In my setup I use a simple geometry field in the Postgis table. This is not a production environment but allows you to have all types of geometry (point, line, polygon) in the same table. I do not define the EPSG code here but I always use EPSG:3857 during development. If you set the table like this you can test whether the WFS-T posts work.

```
CREATE TABLE wfs_geom
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  geometry geometry,
  CONSTRAINT wfs_geom_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE wfs_geom
  OWNER TO geoserver;
```

This is in a new jsfiddle but I can also put this in a stackoverflow code snippet.

https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/13Lwsfmf/

```js
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'https://geolytix.net/wfs',
    featureType: 'wfs_geom',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var xs = new XMLSerializer();

var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('https://maps.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix.wfs/wfs', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'wfs_geom',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    //strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()),
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var interaction;

var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});

var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FF2828'
        })
    })
});

var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: [],
    interactions: [
        interactionSelectPointerMove,
        new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
        new ol.interaction.DragPan()
    ],
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-d}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                opaque: false,
                attributions: []
            })
        }),
        layerWFS
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.7, 53.2]),
        zoom: 6
    })
});

//wfs-t
var dirty = {};
var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
    var node;
    switch (mode) {
        case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
            break;
    }
    var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
    $.ajax('https://maps.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix.wfs/wfs', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: payload
    }).done(function() {
        sourceWFS.clear();
    });
};

$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('btn-active');
    map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear();
    map.removeInteraction(interactionSelect);

    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {

        case 'btnEdit':
            map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: interactionSelect.getFeatures()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            map.addInteraction(interactionSnap);
            dirty = {};
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                e.element.on('change', function (e) {
                    dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                });
            });
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('remove', function (e) {
                var f = e.element;
                if (dirty[f.getId()]) {
                    delete dirty[f.getId()];
                    var featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                    delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                    var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                    clone.setId(f.getId());
                    transactWFS('update', clone);
                }
            });
            break;

        case 'btnPoint':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Point',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnLine':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'LineString',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnArea':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Polygon',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        case 'btnDelete':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
            interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                transactWFS('delete', e.target.item(0));
                interactionSelectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                interaction.getFeatures().clear();
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#btnPoint {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#btnLine {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 80px;
}

#btnArea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 150px;
}

#btnEdit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 220px;
}

#btnDelete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 290px;
}

.btn-active {
  background-color: #0d47a1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <button id="btnPoint" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
      <i class="material-icons">add_location</i>
    </button>
    <button id="btnLine" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
      <i class="material-icons">timeline</i>
    </button>
    <button id="btnArea" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
      <i class="material-icons">signal_cellular_null</i>
    </button>
    <button id="btnEdit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
      <i class="material-icons">build</i>
    </button>
    <button id="btnDelete" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
      <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </button>
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.14/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer is actually correctly processing your request, the problem is that what you are trying to do is not allowed by your underlying datastore. [Shapefiles](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html) must have a geometry attribute called `the_geom` so when you send a geometry called `poly` the shapefile writer ignores it when writing the feature. If you were using a database (e.g. PostGIS) then everything would be fine.

Comment: I've imported the poly shape to a PostGIS database. So now I'm using postgis datastore, but it's still not working. When I create a polygon it puts a new record into the table with a new fid, but without geometry.

Comment: can you add the response for a describeFeature request on the layer to your question?

Comment: <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp"><xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/><xsd:complexType name="polyType"><xsd:complexContent><xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true"

Comment: type="gml:MultiPolygonPropertyType"/><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:extension></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType><xsd:element name="poly" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="topp:polyType"/></xsd:schema>

Comment: It looks to me like the Geometry column is called `geom` not `poly`

Comment: I've changed the name of the column to poly, but still not better.

Comment: should probably be inserting topp:poly (or whatever your namespace is)

Comment: I've tried something new. I've changed the name of the geometry field from "geom" to "geometry". Something clearly changed, because now I get back an error message:
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Error performing insert: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.vividsolutions
.jts.geom.Geometry</ows:ExceptionText>