# How can i save drawn point on the map to geoserver?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have started studying with openlayers and geoserver recently. I want to save drawn point on the map to geoserver, which path should i follow in openlayers?

Comment: Here is an old answer, although the syntax may have changed slightly for more recent versions of OpenLayers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115620/openlayers3-wfs-t-save-drawing